# How to scroll element into view when it's clicked

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Am looking for something similar to [`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) within Ionic2 to use when I click on a button, for example.

None of the methods detailed in [`ion-content`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/content/Content/) help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please take a look at **[this working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fOsyCC?p=preview)**

You can use the `scrollTo(x,y,duration)` method [(docs)](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/content/Content/#scrollTo).
The code is pretty simple, first we obtain the position of the target element (a `<p></p>` in this case) and then we use that in the `scrollTo(...)` method. First the view:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar primary>
    <ion-title>
      <span>My App</span>
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

  <button ion-button text-only (click)="scrollElement()">Click me</button>

  <div style="height: 600px;"></div>

  <!-- Notice the #target in the p element -->
  <p #target>Secret message!</p>

  <div style="height: 600px;"></div>

</ion-content>
```

And the component code:

```
import { ViewChild, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, Content } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl:"home.html"
})
export class HomePage {
  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
  @ViewChild('target') target: any;

  constructor() {   }

  public scrollElement() {
    // Avoid reading the DOM directly, by using ViewChild and the target reference
    this.content.scrollTo(0, this.target.nativeElement.offsetTop, 500);
  }
}
```

Comment: The link to the plunker doesn't seem to display anything related to the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry @Willwsharp, the plunker used an older version of Ionic. I'll create  a new plunker later today :)

Comment: @Willwsharp I've updated the answer to avoid reading the DOM directly. Now it uses `ViewChild` to get the reference of the HTML element

Answer (score 3):

The ion-content **should** have methods for scrolling to particular child elements, however deep. The current methods are okay, but one perspective of the purpose of ionic is to make laborious, boring code like `document.getElementById` obsolete.

The methods also lack control over the scroll animation.

Hence currently the best option is the `scrollIntoView` method. Attach an id to the element you wish to scroll to, then use getElementbyID to call scrollIntoView. So:

**.html**

```html
...
<ion-row id="myElement">

...

</ion-row>
```

**ts**

```js
...
 scrollToMyElement() {
    document.getElementById('myElement').scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
      block: 'center'
    });
  }
```

Then call the method on some DOM event or button click. If your element is conditional this will likely not work. Instead use a conditional **hidden** attribute or, if you must use **ngIf**, time the logic as such that the element is inserted first.

I've tried this with various other ionic (4) UI components and it works fine.

Comment: This works very well.. but not angular specific code, :) use 
@ViewChild('myDiv') myDiv: ElementRef;
this.myDiv.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
      block: 'center'
    });

Answer (score 3):

For Ionic-4 there are multiple changes in the terms used

1. **Content** is changed to **IonContent**
2. **scrollTo** is changed to **scrollToPoint**
3. **ionic-angular** is changed to **@ionic/angular**
4. viewChild has to have **{ static: false }** // only if you are using angular >8.0

Here is the code modified of the accepted answer for ionic-4

```
<ion-header>
      <ion-navbar primary>
        <ion-title>
          <span>My App</span>
        </ion-title>
      </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>    
      <button ion-button text-only (click)="scrollElement(target)">Click me</button>

      <div style="height: 600px;"></div>

      <!-- Notice the #target in the p element -->
      <p #target>Secret message!</p>

      <div style="height: 600px;"></div>
</ion-content>
```

component Code :

```
import { ViewChild, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonContent } from '@ionic/angular'; // change-1

@Component({
  templateUrl:"home.html"
})
export class HomePage {
   @ViewChild('target', { static: false }) target: ElementRef;
   @ViewChild('ion_content', { static: false }) ionContent: IonContent; //change-2 for angular > 8.0 remove this for angular 6.x

  constructor() {   }

  public scrollElement($target) {
    this.ionContent.scrollToPoint(0, $target.offsetTop, 500); 
    //$target (prefered if you have multiple scroll target) could be this.target.nativeElement
  }
}
```

Comment: perfect thanks! I had to use `@ViewChild(IonContent, { static: false }) ionContent: IonContent;` but everything else was perfect

Comment: Joshua Ohana is right, especially for ionic 5

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an anker link in HTML.

Just give the elemnt and id="scrollXYZ" and wrap the button in an

Example:

```
<a href="#scrollXYZ"><button>Example</button></a>
<div id="scrollXYZ"><h2>Scroll to this</h2></div>
```

Comment: This will not work if the element is added dynamically

Comment: @Mackelito it will if you add the scrollTo dynamically too.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the above solution don't work well with Angular Universal server-side rendering (SSR) due to `document` not being available server-side.

Hence I wrote a convenient plugin to achieve scrolling to elements in Angular 4+ that work with `AoT` and `SSR`

NPM
[ngx-scroll-to](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to)

GitHub
[ngx-scroll-to](https://github.com/nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to)

Comment: Best solution I think

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do this in Ionic 3 and due to the fact that `<Element>.offsetTop` was returning`10` (the padding on the top of the element) instead of the distance to the top of the page (much larger unknown number) I ending up just using `<Element>.scrollIntoView()`, which worked well for me.

To get the `<Element>` object I used `document.getElementById()`, but there are many other options on how to get a handle on that.

Answer (score 0):

In `Ionic 4` the scroll function is renamed to `scrollToPoint()`.

[image: Screenshot from Ionic docs]

Answer (score 0):

Can I use scrollToPoint on div instead of content when I have fixed content and the scroll on div or form.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30265013)