# angular 2 - How to get HTMLElement / ElementRef of child component using template reference variable?

Tags: angular, dom, autoscroll, viewchild

I'm trying to get element of child component using ViewChild but can't find a way to achieve this.

Let's say in template:

```
...
<some-comp #someComp></some-comp>
...
```

and getting this reference by:

```
import { SomeComponent } from './some-comp/some-comp.component';
...
@ViewChild('someComp') someComp: SomeComponent;
...
ngOnInit() {
// this.someComp.nativeElement? <-- how to get nativeElement?
}
```

The reason why I'm trying to do this is to focus the view to that child component by auto scrolling to that child component's position using `scrollTo` function of HTMLElement.(see [How to scroll element into view when it's clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39396908/how-to-scroll-element-into-view-when-its-clicked))

I can achieve it by giving id to that child component and retrieve using document.getElementById(), but I'm wondering if there's a way to do this using template reference variable or any angular way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: like this `@ViewChild('someComp', {read: ElementRef}) someComp;` ?

Comment: @Maximus exactly what I was looking for! Can you write "your answer" as answer to this question so that I can mark it as answer to this question? It'll surely help more people who face the same problem :)

Comment: yeah, sure, done

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`@ViewChild` decorator can query several different types which can be specified using `read` parameter:

```
@ViewChild(selector, {read: Type}) property;
```

Those types can be:

- ElementRef

  `@ViewChild('someComp', {read: ElementRef}) someComp;`
- ViewContainerRef

  `@ViewChild('someComp', {read: ViewContainerRef}) someComp;`

In your case it's `ElementRef` that you want.