# How can I scroll down to the my child route?

Tags: angular

How can I scroll down to the my child route using angualr 2/4?

For example I have parent component `P` and child component `C`. On a click function am routing to `C` from `P`. But the issue is that the view window is still in `P` template.

My expectation is to move it to `C` template, why it doesn't?

Comment: please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39406376/1791913

Comment: the solution seems to be related to ionic framework(Mobile)..
Could you help for web application only